# PHP detect if session cookies are disabled

Tags: php, session, cookies, client

I know that with sessions in php, a cookie that stores the session ID is set on the client's side. The client can turn off these cookies, which I presumes makes sessions not work. How can I detect if the client has disabled the session cookies?

Comment: ...Did you try adding a cookie and then seeing if you could read it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `navigator.cookieEnabled`. This returns `true` or `false`.

So

```
if(navigator.cookieEnabled)
    //do something
else
    //do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you started a session on a previous page...

```
<?php 
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
{
  echo 'cookies & sessions enabled';
}
else
{
  echo 'no cookies or sessions';
}
?>
```

or you're looking for a non-session cookies as well.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_COOKIE)) 
{ 
  echo 'cookies are tasty';
} 
else 
{
  echo 'no cookies to eat';
}
?>
```

with a pure php solution you can't check if sessions/cookies are enabled without setting a cookie on a previous page

Answer (score 0):

If you know you MUST use a session, the usual approach is to redirect the user instantly at the start while trying to set a cookie, and then complain about the cookie not being set on the second page.

1. User goes to http://www.example.com
2. System sets a cookie (maybe only starts the session, maybe a dedicated test cookie).
3. System redirects to http://www.example.com/?cookietest=true
4. On that page, if the cookie is not sent back, complain to the user.

On the other hand, most of the time a session really is not needed if you do not have to log someone in. And IF you do, most users will understand they need to allow cookies, because otherwise the login will fail.